# watchdog with Pool in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool, watchdog

I have a simple watchdog in python 3 that reboots my server if something goes wrong:

```
import time, os
from multiprocessing import Pool

def watchdog(x):
    time.sleep(x)
    os.system('reboot')

    return

def main():
    while True:
        p = Pool(processes=1)
        p.apply_async(watchdog, (60, ))    # start watchdog with 60s interval

        # here some code thas has a little chance to block permanently...
        # reboot is ok because of many other files running independently 
        # that will get problems too if this one blocks too long and
        # this will reset all together and autostart everything back
        # block is happening 1-2 time a month, mostly within a http-request

        p.terminate()
        p.join()

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`p = Pool(processes=1)` is declared every time the while loop starts.

Now here the question: **Is there any smarter way?**

If I `p.terminate()` to prevent the process from reboot, the Pool becomes closed for any other work. Or is there even nothing wrong with declaring a new Pool every time because of garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process).  Processes support all of the features you are using, so you don't need to make a pool with size one.  While processes do have a warning about using the `terminate()` method (since it can corrupt pipes, sockets, and locking primitives), you are not using any of those items and don't need to care.  (In any event, `Pool.terminate()` probably has the same issues with pipes etc. even though it lacks a similar warning.)

Comment: But I still have to declare a new process on every loop.

Comment: @Richy: Yes, you do.  You want to spawn a new process every loop, right?

Comment: Should be no problem and Process is cleaner than Pool, thank for that. ;)